# C++ error: output not defined in namespace

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

Update: I made Sergii's changes below, but now I get the error:  undefined reference to `cs202::operator<<(std::basic_ostream >&, cs202::Rational const&)'.  Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks

I would appreciate help figuring out why I am getting this error: 
"error: 'output' is not a member of namespace 'cs202'"

I have a class called Rational as follows:

```
 #ifndef RATIONAL_H
 #define RATIONAL_H

namespace cs202{

class Rational
{
private:

    int m_numerator;
    int m_denominator;

public:

    Rational(int nNumerator = 0, int nDenominator = 1) {
        m_numerator = nNumerator;
        m_denominator = nDenominator;
    }

    int getNumerator(){return m_numerator;}
    int getDenominator(){return m_denominator;}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Rational& cRational);

   };
    }

    #endif
```

The implementation file for the friend function which overrides the << operator looks like this:

```
  #include "rational.h"

  namespace cs202{

     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Rational& cRational)
  {
      output << cRational.m_numerator << "/" << cRational.m_denominator;
     return output;
  }

  }
```

Finally, Main looks like this:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include "rational.h"

  using namespace std;
  using namespace cs202;

  int main()
  {
      Rational fraction1(1, 4);

      cs202::output << fraction1 << endl;

      return 0;
  }
```

I have tried using cout instead of cs202:output, I have tried with and without the namespace cs202 (which is a requirement of the assignment), and I have tried making the operator overload function a member function of the class rather than a friend function to no avail.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: error seems pretty clear, I don't sees `output` define anywhere in the `cs202` namespace

Comment: Instead of cs202::output, it should be std::cout or cout (in case you are including a using std statement.

Comment: Please learn to read error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want it out to standard output (to console)

```
int main()
{
    Rational fraction1(1, 4);

    std::cout << fraction1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Also you do not need friend here. "Friend" keyword is used only in a class

```
#include "rational.h"

namespace cs202{

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Rational& cRational)
{
    output << cRational.m_numerator << "/" << cRational.m_denominator;
    return output;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I figured it out. I had to change the placement of the {} for the namespace.